# Vehicle Routing(VRP) with Optaplanner

Tags: optimization, drools, optaplanner, traveling-salesman

I'm customizing provided Optaplanner VRP example to my needs.

I'm stuck with the Vehicle Capacity problem.

**Capacity = Maximum hours available to a vehicle in a day(X hours)**

> Overview -
>
> Vehicles need to be scheduled for Time Windowed Customers.
>
> We have customer orders from Monday to Friday. Currently I'm inputting
>   the whole week data and letting the algorithm schedule.
>
> Problem with this approach - Vechicle's capacity = X * 5(days) hours.
>
> Over the week Vehicles have X * 5 hrs, but vehicles are constrained to
>   use at max X hrs in a day. With this approach Optaplanner assumes it
>   has X * 5 hrs as Vehicle capacity and schedule Vehicles accordingly.

- **How to constrain vehicle to use at max X hrs in a day?**
  or
- **How to schedule on day to day basis?**
  or
- **How to reset the Capacity when the next day starts? (Every day vehicles will have X hrs to start with)**

Any insights to solve would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I too have similar queries.